# C# - String replace with Ignore Case as Well as Whole Word Only in .Net Framework without Regex

Tags: c#, regex, replace

Regex is not replacing special characters properly. So any alternative or
codes to fix this method.

Until now I was using this method from regex to replace

```
public static string Replace(this string s,string word ,string by ,bool IgnoreCase,bool WholeWord)
    {
        RegexOptions regexOptions = RegexOptions.None;
        if (IgnoreCase) regexOptions = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;
        if (WholeWord) word = @"\b" + Regex.Escape(word) + @"\b";
        return Regex.Replace(s, word, by, regexOptions);
    }
```

I have a string

```
string str = "Apple , Mango , Banana.";
```

if I replace

```
str = str.Replace("apple", "Apples", true, true);
```

Results

```
Apples, Mango, Banana.
```

It works fine with any letter(s) or digit(s), but it didn't work on non-letter-digit like comma(,), dot(.) and others @,#,$,",:

Example

```
str = str.Replace(",", " and ", true, true);
```

It didn't do anything.

Another Example I have string "She is Mari and she is Marijane.";
if I want to Replace Mari to Mira
Normal Replace will Replace both Mari and Marijane
Some places Mari is at beginnig and some places at end connected with fullstop(.) or sometimes used with commas.

Note: I need both IgnoreCase and WholeWord as bool

There are some examples already, but none of them can combine (IgnoreCase and WholeWord), and I need in .Net Framework 4.8 (It uses C# version 7.3 or lower)

So please somebody could Help me in this situation

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English

Comment: "\b" will only match on a transition between a "word" character and a "non-word" character. So "\b,\b" would only match something like "a,a", and "\b and \b" would only match something like "a and a". See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#WordCharacter, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/anchors-in-regular-expressions#word-boundary-b

Comment: So How can use all these Escape Characters Together

Comment: I suspect that you should only append / prepend "\b" if the input string starts or ends with a word character. In other words, you should not pass `WholeWord = true` if you are matching `","`.

Comment: No I need to Replace Exact word whether it word or non-word like Replace("Apple,","",true,true); to rid first item and I also want to replace word ends with fullstop(.) in paragraph

Comment: A punctuation symbol (such as a comma) is NOT a word. It's a single punctuation character. You can't expect to treat it as a word, because it's not one. Words are composed of letters, and are surrounded by spaces on either site unless they're  the first thing or the last thing in a sentence or paragraph.

Comment: Have you tried using just `str = str.Replace(",", " and ");` ? I would be very surprised if this didn't work because I've used exactly that sort of replace in the past.

Comment: I need both IgnoreCase and WholeWord as options like in Notepad++ provides us

Comment: I think your `Replace` extension method is adding more confusion to your problem. You probably need to construct specific regular expressions for your specific use case. But you haven't provided enough detail of the entire problem you are trying to solve. You've only said that `str.Replace(",", " and ", true, true);` doesn't work, not what you expected the output to be.

Comment: I want to Replace all Characters in Like notepad++ for TextToSpeech Replacements (These commas and fullstop giving me trouble to replace)

Comment: Think you need to stop trying to find one ring to rule them all; for your comma scenario do a normal replace like slugster recommended, not a Regex replace.. or you're going to have to understand that the `,` in `apples , bananas` doesn't have a transition from word char to no word char either side of it so you should *not* do a whole-word replace. Other punctuation may fail (like replace `.` with `x` will turn the whole string to `x` ) because it means something special to Regex, like "any char", and would need escaping

Comment: All in your complaint seems to be "Regex replace isn't doing what I want" but it's because there are some nuances of Regex that you're not considering, and you're asking it to make replacements that aren't actually what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can Answer to that Question for older version of .NET Frameworks without Using So Called Regex or Third-Party Package

**Just use These Codes.**

```
public static string Replace(this string s, string word, string by, StringComparison stringComparison, bool WholeWord)
    {
        s = s + " ";
        int wordSt;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (s.IndexOf(word, stringComparison) > -1)
        {
            wordSt = s.IndexOf(word, stringComparison);
            if (!WholeWord || ((wordSt == 0 || !Char.IsLetterOrDigit(char.Parse(s.Substring(wordSt - 1, 1)))) && !Char.IsLetterOrDigit(char.Parse(s.Substring(wordSt + word.Length, 1)))))
            {
                sb.Append(s.Substring(0, wordSt) + by);
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append(s.Substring(0, wordSt + word.Length));
            }
            s = s.Substring(wordSt + word.Length);
        }
        sb.Append(s);
        return sb.ToString().Substring(0, sb.Length - 1);
    }
```

If you want **StringComparison** as bool then Add this

```
public static string Replace(this string s, string word, string by, bool IgnoreCase, bool WholeWord)
    {
        StringComparison stringComparison = StringComparison.Ordinal;
        if (IgnoreCase) stringComparison = StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
        return s.Replace(word, by, stringComparison, WholeWord);
    }
```

You Can Either Keep Both or Merge them. It's all up to you.